# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets "The specified path, file name,or both are too long"

Tags: azure, publish

I am trying to publish a project to Windows Azure but get an error in the generated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets file related to length of paths and file names. How can I determine which is the problematic path or filename. The error relates to the "" tag in the generated file
Thanks
Martin

Comment: My first guess would be that you buried the Visual Studio solution too deep in the file system so that when packaging your solution one of the resulting paths exceeds 260 chars (NTFS restriction)...

Answer (score 4):

Already an older post - did you check this post?
[Path too long error when building a windows azure service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739347/path-too-long-error-when-building-a-windows-azure-service)

This might reslove your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was still a problem for me years later and the above doesn't apply to Azure SDK v2.8, I was able to solve it by creating a symbolic link to my projects folder.  Open up the command prompt as an administrator and run this:

```
mklink /D C:\Dev C:\Users\danzo\Source\Workspaces
```

Obviously you can change "C:\Dev" to whatever you want it to be and you'll need to change the longer path above to the root directory of your soltions/projects folder.