# Microsoft Azure - Deploying ASP.NET solution - Path too long error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

First, I'd like to explain that I tried the suggestions offered here:[Path too long error when building a windows azure service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739347/path-too-long-error-when-building-a-windows-azure-service). None of these solutions seem to work for my situation.

To summarize, I'm simply trying to to deploy an ASP.NET web forms app to my already-established Azure web app service. I see the following error:

Copying file packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0.nupkg to C:\Users\stevieray8450\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\FrankiesDiscountAutos1-982367110\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0.nupkg failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.  FrankiesDiscountAutos1      0

The path is ridiculously long, as you can see. Are there any other suggestions? Much appreciated!

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it that will help more communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue before. And I resolved it 
by setting the **_CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY** to a shorter path, say “C:\A” for example. It is also in you mentioned [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739347/path-too-long-error-when-building-a-windows-azure-service). We also can get more detail information from this [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jnak/2010/01/14/windows-azure-resolving-the-path-is-too-long-after-being-fully-qualified-error-message/). If you have't tried this, please have a try.

> **Note**: Make sure that you close Visual Studio and **shutdown** the development fabric by using the “**csrun /devfabric:shutdown**” command I mentioned above or by clicking “exit” on the Windows Azure the tray icon.