# Service fabric: Failed to create destination directory for copying file

Tags: azure, logging, azure-service-fabric, diagnostics

Currently running Service Fabric in a few different environments, and have seen the following error in the event logs:

> Failed to create destination directory for copying file Fabric\540714622a10d5490128672dab45ac31_fabric_traces_5.6.220.9494_131490962602842278_1251_00636431511955855132_0000000000.dtr.zip.
>   Exception information: System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified
>   path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name
>   must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less
>   than 248 characters.
>   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>   at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
>   at FabricDCA.FileShareUploader.CopyFileToDestination(String source,
>   String sourceRelative, Int32 retryCount, Boolean& fileSkipped)

Does not *seem* to be impacting our services but the error is thrown every couple of minutes and jams up the logs, as it is thrown 100+ times.

Could only find a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739347/path-too-long-error-when-building-a-windows-azure-service), the suggested fix is to edit the project files in order to shorten the output path but I am not convinced this is my issue...The path to the fabric logs is well within the character limit (at about 160), so it seems as though something else is going on.

There are .dtr files being successfully written to the Lease and Fabric folders but, as mentioned, every few minutes a large amount of the logs are failing.

Has anyone had similar issues? Am I missing something simple?

Currently running Service Fabric v5.6.220.9494.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to a bug in the Service Fabric code. If you try updating to version 6.0, there is a fix in there.